# How to start only one taskmanager in flink 1.7.0, if it got killed somehow?

Tags: apache-flink

Let Say

```
Server 1 : Job Manager and Taskmanager 1
Server 2 : Taskmanager 2
Server 3 : Taskmanager 3
```

I killed the Taskamanager 2 forcefully.

**Problem Statement:**

I need to start Taskmanager 2 only.

For starting Taskmanger 2, I need restart the cluster.

Is there any other way?

Comment: their is no need to restart the cluster in order to start/kill task managers .
How do you run your cluster ? standalone yarn other ?

Comment: Got the answer. Thanks for replying @MIkCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

Go to that particular server and start by using the command *./taskmanager.sh start*.